# Is there anyway to detect when a user goes to their homescreen and back into their browser?

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile, safari, chromium

I need to be able to detect when a user re-opens their browser after they go to their homescreen by clicking the home button on a mobile phone.

Is there an event I can subscribe to or something?

**EDIT: To make this extremely clear, I am looking for a solution based in the web, not a mobile app. I need a js event or something to detect when my website is reopened.**

Answer (score 0):

The [unload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unload_event) event can be monitored to check if the page has been closed dues to navigation away from the page or specific user action has been take to close the page.

The [beforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event) evemt is similar to `unload` but it may be possible to ask if the user wants to stay on the page.  If you want to debug when this event occurs I would suggest saving a message in local storage and logging (or otherwise alerting) it in debug code when the page is loaded again.

The [blur](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/blur_event) event can be used to see if the page has lost focus by checking the `relatedTarget` property of the event object - if focus has been transferred off page it will be `null`.

None of these can implicitly check if the user actually went to the home screen and came back, and I would consider it a security breach if you could tell exactly. The blur event can at least tell if the page has lost focus, but will fire in a desktop environment if the user clicks on, say, the address bar.